# Is there an alternative firmware for the D-Link DIR-600 C1 wireless router?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware

I just bought a D-Link DIR-600 Wireless Router and was hoping to setup a VPN Server/Client using dd-wrt firmware.

But unfortunately my hardware version of DIR-600, known as C1, is not supported by dd-wrt.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: Not a duplicate!! I asked specificaly about the C1 hardware version!!